# How to get fragments in mobile legends?

Tags: mobile-legends

I want to buy Nana's Graveyard Party, but I only have 3 fragments. How do I get more? I'm new to this game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it on free chest every 4 hour if you are lucky.

Complete quests & login daily to get free chests gold chests have a great chance of having the skin fragments.

Also keep an eye on the lucky spin, it is also a great resource for getting fragments.

Also see here: https://forum.mobilelegends.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=11760